# Ubuntu SDK: How do I implement a “onClick” for an image in QML?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

I have a background image for my page, and I want to implement a sort of page refresh when the background is clicked. However, I didn't find any actions for the image element in QT quick.

What's the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [MouseArea](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/QtQuick.MouseArea/) to handle click events.

```
Image {
    source: "myimage.png"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            // do what you want here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! 
Completely missed that in the documentation! Coming from an iOS background I was instinctively looking for a "gesture recognizer".